# react useState hook variable value don't update on input onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react useState hook won't update on input onChange event using react functional component

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
// i'm not able to set input value in useeffect using this code
<GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
  <CustomInput
    labelText="Email address"
    id="email-address"
    formControlProps={{
      fullWidth: true
    }}

    value={email}
    onChange={evt => setEmail(evt.target.value)}
  />
</GridItem>
```

Comment: What does the code (especially the ‘onChange’ part) of your ‘CustomInput’ look like? The code you provided here seems fine to me. Custom components don’t natively inherit eventListeners so my guess is that the problem is in that component instead

Comment: Could you paste all the code of your `CustomInput` Component?

Comment: I'm using material-ui theme and i want to store data using axios but useState don't set input value,here is my code

Comment: @rinkal satasiya don't use onChange here. use inside CustomInput

Comment: @rinkalsatasiya check this example, hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497648/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{email}</h4>
      <CustomInput handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CustomInput.js

```
import React from "react";

function CustomInput(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your function?

```
onChange={e => this.setEmail(e)} // use arrow function to bind this

setEmail = (e) => {
  yourSetFunction({[e.target.name]:e.target.value}) // assuming you give you input a name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setEmail(e.target.value);
}
// i'm not able to set input value in useeffect using this code
<GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
  <CustomInput
    labelText="Email address"
    id="email-address"
    formControlProps={{
      fullWidth: true
    }}

    value={email}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</GridItem>
```